# how to use bower in existing project?

Tags: angularjs, bower

just starting out with bower and angularjs , how can I download all the dependencies for my project. It contains a bower.json file and bowerrc file? which command do I run from the root?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://bower.io/):

> Using the dependencies listed in the current directory's bower.json

```
bower install
```

If you haven't installed bower, you'll need to do that first:

```
npm install -g bower
```

If you haven't installed node and npm you'll need to do that before you do anything:

[How to install Node.js](http://howtonode.org/how-to-install-nodejs)

Comment: I am actually running this from the commandline and it says: 'bower' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Comment: You don't have bower installed, or it is not on your path. If you've got node and npm installed, try running npm install -g bower.

Comment: what is the path for bower?

Comment: The path is wherever you installed it. My path is /usr/local/bin/. What OS are you running this on?

Comment: Okay, I'm on a Mac and I don't have much experience with node on Windows. Are you positive you've installed bower?